# adding an application to a profile tab in facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook, profile, tabs

I have created an application which needs to have a profile box tab which has a link in it pointing to the main application.

However I've tried to add the application to the tab as you can see in the screenshot but it doesn't seem to be appearing as a tab (there is not mention of the application within the tabs).

Can anyone shed some light?

http://img136.imageshack.us/img136/2051/facebookscreenshot.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found in the end was to use [the static fbml apllication](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878).